# Overriding implicit rule of certain targets without interfering with -MMD

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Say I have a simple `Makefile` like so:

```
CXXFLAGS+=-O3 -Wall -pednatic -MMD -Isrc

SRCS=$(shell find src -name '*.cpp')
OBJS=${SRCS:.cpp=.o}

TEST_SRCS=$(shell find test -name '*.cpp')
TEST_OBJS=${TEST_SRCS:.cpp=.o}

all: bin/product

bin/product: $(OBJS)
  $(CXX) ($CXX_FLAGS) -o $@ $^

test: test/runner
  ./test/runner

test/runner: $(TEST_OBJS) $(OBJS)
  $(CXX) ($CXX_FLAGS) -o $@ $^

-include ${OBJS:.o=.d}
-include ${TEST_OBJS:.o=.d}

.PHONY: all test
```

The important bits to note here are that I have two separate binary targets (one production with objects from `src/` and one test runner with objects from both `src/` and `test/`). I want to change the `CXXFLAGS` just for targets in test (`test/runner`, but also `test/foo_test.o`) but not in `src`. I could of course define my own rule to override the implicit one (note the added `-Itest`, which is one of many differences in how I'd like to compile tests):

```
test/%.o: test/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -Itest -c -o $@ $^
```

But this has the unfortunate consequence of overriding the dependencies from the included `*.d` files created by `-MMD`. For example `test/foo_test.d`:

```
test/foo_test.o: test/foo_test.cpp src/foo.o
```

Is there any way to override the implicit rule for objects in `test/` without losing the dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define or modify make variables on a per target basis (see [GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific)):

```
$(TEST_OBJS): CXX_FLAGS += -Itest
```

Notes:

- You shouldn't use the same `CXX_FLAGS` for compilation and linking. The options are different. For instance, you do not pass `-I...` options to the linker. Use `LDFLAGS` for linking, instead.
- Your Makefile uses `CXXFLAGS` and `CXX_FLAGS`. Typos in your question? The standard make variable to pass options to the C++ compiler is `CXXFLAGS`, not `CXX_FLAGS`.

Comment: And that does it! Thanks so much for the explanation! Yeah `CXX_FLAGS` was a typo. I was trying to make my actual `Makefile` a bit more generally applicable and got sloppy. Sorry for the confusion & thanks again!